# .NET npgsql exception not readable symbols

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

Getting error from PostgreSQL in C# but cannot read it.
This is what i have in `NpgsqlException` text:

```
Additional information: �����: 28000: � pg_hba.conf ��� ������, ����������� ����������� ��� ���������� � ���������� "192.168.88.1" ��� ������������ "postgres", ���� ������ "testdb", SSL ����.
```

Is there any way to set different language for this? Or any other fix to make it readable?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with the PostgreSQL version 3 protocol. The server sends error messages in the system's default text encoding until the connection handshake has got far enough along to allow the client to specify what text encoding it expects from the server.

However, the server never tells the client what its default text encoding is, so the client doesn't know how to decode messages from early in the connection process. Most drivers assume the text is in their current default text encoding, but if that's wrong, you get garbage.

This is slated to be fixed in the next revision of the network protocol, but that probably won't be for quite some time. In the mean time, as you have found, changing the server's default locale to use an encoding that the client will expect, like `utf-8`, is the best workaround. The easiest way to do this is by changing `lc_messages` in `postgresql.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.
On the server in the **postgresql.conf** file i changed **lc_messages** option to **'en_EN.UTF-8'**.
**`lc_messages = 'en_EN.UTF-8'`**